# Unreal Engine and Clion (can't resolve some sybmols)

Tags: c++, windows-10, clion, unreal-engine4

UE 4.23

CLion 2019.2.1 (clangd server off)

After testing this newbie [tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/QuickStart/index.html?utm_source=launcher&utm_medium=ue&utm_campaign=uelearn) i have many unresolved symbols in `clion` like on picture:

[image]

Only when I add `this->` to variable or method - the red letters are disappear.
How avoid this?

Comment: I suppose this is a CMake project opened in CLion, am I right? And why the Clangd is turned off? Also, have you tried building the project?

Comment: That looks like a bug, but requires further investigation. Could you please submit a code sample to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17389

Answer (score 1):

In your `FloatingActor.cpp` file, add the following includes after `#include "FloatingActor.h"`:

```
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "ConstructorHelpers.h"
```

will solve the problem.

Please note that you should only put these includes inside the `.cpp` file, not the `.h` file.

Here are my includes in `.cpp` file and `.h` file.

- FloatingActor.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "FloatingActor.generated.h"
```

- FloatingActor.cpp

```
#include "FloatingActor.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "ConstructorHelpers.h"
```

More discussions [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1671051-programming-quick-start-and-compiler-doesnt-like-it).